# Two different decomposition of scaled identity matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbf{\Sigma} = (1/2)I_2$ where $I_2$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. Give two different selections for $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ with $\lambda_1+ \lambda_2 =1 $ and $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2 \in \mathbb{C}^2 $ with $ ||\mathbf{v}_1||= ||\mathbf{v}_2||=1$ such that $ \mathbf{\Sigma} = \lambda_1 \mathbf{v}_1\mathbf{v}_1^H + \lambda_2 \mathbf{v}_2\mathbf{v}_2^H $

I know the first set of solutions is obtained from EVD with $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1/2 $ and $ \mathbf{v}_1 = [1, \; 0]^T, \mathbf{v}_2 = [0, \; 1]^T$.
I wonder what is the other set of solution such that the decomposition of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is not unique.

Comment: For $v_1$ and $v_2$ we can take any orthonormal pair of vectors still with $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1/2$. What happens if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not orthogonal?